# Bash group csv data by values

Tags: json, bash, csv

I have a CSV that looks like this:

```
created,id,value
2022-12-16 11:55,58,10
2022-12-16 11:55,59,2
2022-12-16 11:50,58,11
2022-12-16 11:50,59,3
2022-12-16 11:50,60,7
```

I want to parse it so I have the following result, setting ids as columns and grouping by date:

```
created,58,59,60
2022-12-16 11:55,10,2,nan
2022-12-16 11:50,11,3,7
```

missing values are set to nan, each id appears at most once per date

How can I do it? I also have the first CSV in a JSON equivalent if this is easier to do with jq

The JSON is composed of similar elements:

```json
{ 
  "created": "2022-12-16 09:15", 
  "value": "10.4", 
  "id": "60" 
}
```

Comment: Please add to your question (no comment): What have you searched for, and what did you find? What have you tried, and how did it fail?

Comment: I do not understand thefirst line of the example output you want. What is the "created" doing here ? Is the first line of the output supposed to contain a list of all the IDs found in the data file ?

Comment: @Itération122442 Yes, the output is a CSV so the first line is a header with the column names. You can name 'created' as 'date' if you want, it was just the original name. The objective is to have the date and all the ids as column names.

Comment: @Cyrus It is not an error or something I can fix, it is something I want to do and don't know how. I have originally a JSON file obtained from an API, in which the elements are like: 
```
{
        "created": "2022-12-16 09:15",
        "value": "10.4",
        "id": "60"
    } 
```
I have used jq to get the CSV that I first present, but didn't found a way to get what I want, so I was thinking that a CSV file is easier to process, with sed or awk maybe

Comment: Have you tried this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/74832655/757714

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the great [Miller](https://miller.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installing-miller/) (version >= 6), running

```
mlr --csv reshape -s id,value then unsparsify then fill-empty -v "nan" input.csv
```

you get

```
created,58,59,60
2022-12-1611:55,10,2,nan
2022-12-1611:50,11,3,7
```

The core command here is `reshape -s id,value`, to transform your input from long to wide structure.

Comment: It is indeed working well, thanks! I didn't know this tool, it seems very useful. I have to note that this is not working if there are spaces after the commas.

Comment: @nicod it seems to me that my answer is very good. Moreover miller can do the same operation on the JSON, but you started from the CSV and I responded to that. It makes no sense to add anything, and by the way you have already chosen the right answer for you.

Comment: Yes your answer is also perfect, but I can only mark one as 'Accepted'. In my script I finally used the jq only solution to avoid external dependencies, but miller is definitely an awesome tool. For me, both of your answers respond perfectly to my request so I can put yours as 'Accepted' if that makes you happy, but think that the other one can also be upset for the exact same reason as you...

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it in jq, based on the JSON input stream:

```bash
reduce inputs as {$created, $value, $id} ({head: [], body: {}};
  .head |= (.[index($id) // length] = $id) | .body[$created][$id] = $value
)
| (.head | sort_by(tonumber)) as $head | ["created", $head[]], (
  .body | to_entries[] | [.key, .value[$head[]]]
)
```

Then, either use the `@csv` builtin which wraps the values in quotes, and produces empty values for missing combinations:

```bash
jq -nr '
  ⋮
  | @csv
'
```

```
"created","2","3","10","11","50","55","58","59"
"2022-12-16 11:55","6",,"3",,,"4","2","5"
"2022-12-16 11:50",,"12",,"9","10",,"8","11"
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/pDrI8e172pN)

Or generate `nan` and `,` manually by `map`ping and `join`ing accordingly:

```bash
jq -nr '
  ⋮
  | map(. // "nan") | join(",")
'
```

```
created,2,3,10,11,50,55,58,59
2022-12-16 11:55,6,nan,3,nan,nan,4,2,5
2022-12-16 11:50,nan,12,nan,9,10,nan,8,11
```

[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/wVqrlvTycth)

Comment: Amazing, I didn't know enough jq to do that. thank you for your help!